# Bootstrap interferindo ImageAreaSelect (Primefaces)

Tags: css, css3, jsf, primefaces, bootstrap

Estou utilizando o componente, do primefaces Extesions, chamado ImageAreaSelect.

[Primefaces Extesion - ImageAreaSelect](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/imageAreaSelect/basicSelection.jsf)

Porem esta TAG do Bootstrap está fazendo com que o **background** do ImageAreaSelect está ficando desproporcional.

```
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box
}
:after,
:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
```

Esta imagem é o background com problema 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para solucionar este problema? se eu tirar o CSS o template fica bugado.

Eu estava pensando em solucionar o problema tirando o **background** do **ImageAreaSelect** porem não faço ideia de qual TAG ele usa.

Tambem não achei na documentação do primefaces

Comment: Use a opção Inspect/Inspecionar do Google Chrome sobre o componente que você encontra o CSS que ele usa.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazendo o seguinte

```
.pe-imgageareaselect-outer {
    display: none !important;
}

.pe-imgageareaselect-selection {
    background: black !important;
}
```